Showing $\binom{n}{k} =\frac{n(n−1)···(n−k+1)}{k!}$
Just one line in Burton's number theory has made me waste hours and facepalm myself in shame.
Here it is:

$$\binom{n}{k} =\frac{n(n−1)···(k+1)}{(n-k)!}=
 \frac{n(n−1)···(n−k+1)}{k!}$$

First derivation is alright by me, but how is $\dfrac{n(n−1)···(n−k+1)}{k!}$ derived?
It's a completely jump statement, and I've talked with chatgpt all day hoping I could get my answer, but I haven't. I'm wondering if I can understand this at all. Really need help.
Edit: Thanks for the downvotes, and the answers. I understand it now.

Think of the definition, $\binom nk=\frac {n!}{(n-k)!\times k!}$...you can remove either of the factors in the denominator by cancelling them against factors of the numerator.  Alternatively, note that $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$.

Also I would advise you not to "talk" to ChatGPT to understand maths. You will get a lot of false understanding.

Symmetry.  ${n \choose k}$ and ${n\choose n-k}$ have to be equal.  And we can prove this alegebraically:  If we assume $n-k > k$ then $\frac {n(n-1)....(n-k+1)}{k!}\cdot \frac {(n-k)(n-k-1)....(k+1)}{(n-k)(n-k-1)....(k+1)} = \frac {n(n-1)....(k+1)}{(n-k)!}$.   [... ta-da...?] (And if $k > n-k$ we can do a similar thing.)

You say you believe $$\binom{n}{k} =\frac{n(n−1)\cdots(k+1)}{(n-k)!}.$$ How did you figure it out? But you do not understand why $$\binom{n}{k}=
\frac{n(n−1)\cdots(n−k+1)}{k!}.$$ How is it different?

@CaptainLama what will i even do as someone who self studies this stuff.

We are assuming n-k>k but how do we know n-k>k+1? @fleablood

@DavidK from the original definition of (n k),  all i knew was that k<=n hence i cut out k! and the numerator became n...(k+1), denominator being (n-k)!

Also $n-k \leq n$ so if you cut out $(n-k)!$ what is left is $n\cdots(n-k+1)$ in the numerator and $k!$ in the denominator. It's really the exact same idea.

I would note that the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects to come with you, is the exact same thing as choosing $n-k$ objects to stay behind.  So by symmetry we must have ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n-k}$.
Both of these, meanwhile are equal to $\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!} = \frac {n!}{(n-(n-k))!(n-k)!}$
and to go from $\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac {n\cdot (n-1)...... (n-k+1)(n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac {n\cdot (n-1)...... (n-k+1)}{k!}$ can be done the exact same way as going from  $\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac {n\cdot (n-1)...... (k+1)k!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac {n\cdot (n-1)...... (k+1)}{(n-k)!}$

n-k is less than n, sure, but how is n-k+1 less than n?

nevermind, i get it now.

You can check that $n(n-1)\cdots (k+1)\cdot k! = n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)\cdot (n-k)!$ because they are both clearly equal to $n!$.

but we are assuming k+1< n, n-k+1<n

i get it now, thanks

the problem was chatgpt all along...
